# Going back to smart hub when return key is pressed on samsung tizen tv

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-tv

NOTE : this is different from normal Samsung Smart TV, this one has Tizen OS.

My app got rejected with the defect 
"Return does not take you to previous page like SMART Hub but goes to broadcasting". 
It occurs on 2016 models, works fine on 2015 Tizen TV models.

This is the piece of code that executes on return key press (have put it in apt switch case ) :

```
tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
```

How do I prevent it from going to broadcasting and direct it to Smart Hub?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Please tell me how to solve this issue because I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use window.history.back() , then return should you to previous page

```
if (window.history.length != 0) 
{ 
    window.history.back(); 
} 
else if (window.history.length == 0) 
{ 
    tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To direct it to Smart Hub you may try hide() to close the application.

```
tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().hide();
```

Check the [Document](https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen51/index.html#Hiding-and-exiting-application) for details.

Comment: From the linked docs: 
`hide()` - _If you hide an application, screen goes back to the situation when you launched application._ 
`exit()` - _If you exit an application, screen goes back to the situation when you launched application._ **So, why should `hide()` make any difference here?**

Comment: Yes, you are right. There still remains a difference that exit() forces an app to terminate and hide() forces an app to suspend, but return directions are most probably same.